# htaccess RewriteCond help for new development site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have having a real problem here and I am hoping someone can help me out - let me explain:

I have a site - domain.co.uk - for the past 6 months this site has been sat on holding pages so google gets to know the domain.
I also have domain.com and domain.org - these were also set up at the same time.
We have a new website under development using a Drupal multisite install where all of the multisites are sub-domains.

Here is my problem!! The new website is now under development and I need to add various rules to the htaccess to redirect back to the holding pages but these rules are new to me  and I dont really have a clue what I am doing!

This is what I need to do:
The primary domain is domain.co.uk.
I need to redirect all users requesting domain.co.uk to domain.co.uk/holding/index.php,
but I need to put an IP address exclusion in for us and the developers for testing the new site so we can see what is going on with the new website.
The website also has .com alias and this needs to go to domain.co.uk for all requests.

So here is what I have so far and it does not work as it should:

---

```
// I set this to re-write anything except the subdomains I want to see
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.domain\.co\.uk)|(subdomain1.domain\.co\.uk)|(subdomain2.domain\.co\.uk)|(subdomain3.domain\.co\.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www\.domain\.co\.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

 // then I have put in some rules for checking the ip's and producing a redirect that does not match earlier requests.
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^(xx\.xxx\.xxx\.xx)|(xx\.xx\.xx\.xx)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/holding/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /holding/index\.php [R=302,L]
```

---

The result so far is:

if a general user goes to the domain.co.uk it redirects to the holding page - GOOD
if a user from the 'excluded ip's address list goes to domain.co.uk they also get redirected - BAD - but if they go to .domain.co.uk/index.php the Drupal site loads with the new design.
If a user from the excluded ip's list goes to subdomain1.domain.co.uk they get redirected to the holding pages - BAD-  this, I think, should not happen due to the 1st rule but I am totally lost.

Anyone got any ideas how to get this working so that a user with an allowed ip can access the new website and all it's subdomains but any general user is directed to the holding pages.

Many thanks - my head is about to explode!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${REMOTE_ADDR}` is the IP Address, `${REMOTE_HOST}` is the hostname if available.

You could also temporarily add ${REMOTE_ADDR} into the redirect to the holding page to check that you are putting the right addresses in, e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /holding/index\.php?ip=${REMOTE_ADDR} [R=302,L]
```